# segmentation fault(core dumped) error with quick sort

Tags: segmentation-fault

I am having trouble implementing Quicksort in C++. 
I am not sure why i am receiving a "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" error...
Here is my code. Any help would be very much appreciated. Thank you! 
I am also not quite sure what to make the base case and how to put the left array, pivot, and right array together into one array at the end when they need to be combined.

```
void printVector(vector<int> ar, int ar_size);

    void quickSort(vector <int>  ar, int ar_size) {
        int pivot = ar[0];
        vector <int> left(ar_size);
        int leftcount = 0;
        vector <int> right(ar_size);
        int rightcount = 0;

    for(int i = 0; i < ar_size; i++){
        if(ar[i] < pivot){
            left.push_back(ar[i]);
            leftcount++;
        }
        if(ar[i] >= pivot){
            right.push_back(ar[i]);
            rightcount++;
        }
    }
    if(ar_size <= 2){
        printVector(left, leftcount);
        cout << pivot;
        printVector(right, rightcount);
    }
    if(leftcount>0){
    quickSort(left, leftcount);
    }
    if(rightcount>0){
    quickSort(right, rightcount);
    }

}

void printVector(vector<int> ar, int ar_size){

        for(int i = 0; i<ar_size; i++){

        cout << ar[i] << " ";

    }
}

int main(void) {
   vector <int>  _ar;
   int _ar_size;
cin >> _ar_size;
for(int _ar_i=0; _ar_i<_ar_size; _ar_i++) {
   int _ar_tmp;
   cin >> _ar_tmp;
   _ar.push_back(_ar_tmp); 
}

quickSort(_ar, _ar_size);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: using a debugger would tell you exactly where your problem is

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm "in general" is ok, but there is a lot of problems in here.

First, you probably want to `reserve` memory instead of creating `ar_size` elements in vector on each iteration.

Second, you want to execute loop in `quickSort` starting from `int i = 1` not `int i = 0`, because othewise n biggest elements will always be in `vector<int> right` and you'll get a stack overflow.

Third, and last, your printing/sorting sequence should look like that:

```
if (leftcount>0) {
    quickSort(left, leftcount);
    if (ar_size == 1){
        printVector(left, leftcount);
    }
}

cout << pivot << " ";

if (rightcount>0) {
    quickSort(right, rightcount);
    if (ar_size == 1) {
        printVector(right, rightcount);
    }
}
```